# Geolocation Issue - Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to get the user's position ( Latitude and Longitude) But for some reason it doesn't work. It works in browser but not in phone or emulator. Here is my code.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public _http:Http, public alertCtrl:AlertController, public zone:NgZone, public platform:Platform, public loadingCtrl:LoadingController){        
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        console.log('Condition is true');
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
          console.log(position);
          }, (err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
    }else{
      console.error("Navigator is unavailable");
    }
});}
```

In console I get `Condition is true` but that's the only console log I'm getting nothing else.

Version and Plugin

Cordova version 6.4.0

Ionic version 2.1.4

cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.0 "Geolocation"

Below is the code from www/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">


  <title>Ionic App</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">
   <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDRu7tdUdnsl1-BbA-l-Qcctwa66LBt8Ww"></script>

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->
  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below code is from config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.miyabiairapp257144" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>MiyabiAir</name>
  <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8000*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.4"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
  <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes Sir. It's at the top `import { Geolocation, NativeStorage  } from 'ionic-native';`

Comment: Thank you for your message. Yes I did that one  and still it doesn't work.

Comment: its Xolo one with Android Version 4.4.2 for emulator I'm using Android SDK build for x86 with Android version 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps:

1. ionic run android
2. Close GPS
3. Open GPS
4. Close App
5. Open App

This happens because the app is in debug mode and its related to the permissions of the app to use the GPS

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work. I tried on emulator and different physical device but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it works for me.

```
var posOptions = {timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
  var fromlat = position.coords.latitude;
  var fromlng = position.coords.longitude;
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(fromlat, fromlng);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results);
    }
  });
}, function (err) {
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I replaced `$cordovaGeolocation` with `Geolocation` and tried and it didn't work but I got timeout error. Then I removed timeout from the object and still it doesn't work.

Comment: try to follow this http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/
are you running your project in device ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.

```
import {Geolocation} from 'ionic-native';

export class someThing {
   data: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
        let lat = resp.coords.latitude;
        let lng = resp.coords.longitude;
        this.data.lat = lat;
        this.data.lng = lng;
    });
}
```

}
Would you be able to post your index.html file and your config.xml

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is exactly same as what others suggest and what I tried and please check my question again. I have included www/index.html file and config.xml file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I did the code belowed, you can find an example in my github https://github.com/prolland006/ionic2-geoloc/blob/master/src/services/background-geolocation-service.ts

```
 Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.foreGroundOptions)
        .then((position: Geoposition) => {
            this.trace.info(`Foregrnd current ${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}`);
        }).catch((error)=>{
            if ((error.code == undefined) || (error.code != 3)) { //3=timeout
                this.trace.error('BackgroundGeolocationService', 'refreshLocations', `error Foregrnd.getCurrentPos:${error.toString()}`);
            }
        });
```

maybe you forgot the options

```
  // Foreground Tracking
foreGroundOptions = {
    frequency: 2000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: Infinity,
    timeout: 2000
};
```

Comment: Didn't work. Looks like its a bug or something started new project and installed geolocation plugin and tried to access lat lng but still it doesn't work